# Extract part of filename

Tags: linux, replace, sed, extract, filenames

I have multiple filenames that look something like;

com.test.**app1**.deb

com.heavy.test.**app2**.deb

com.maybe-test.**app3**.deb

com.crazy.**app-4**.deb

I would like to get the bolded strings only. 
so far, I've got this,

```
name=$(echo $file | sed 's!\(*.\)\(.*\).deb!\2!')
```

EDIT: 
I have other files in the same dir that would name something like;

com.company.**name**_1.0.2_arm.deb

Currently, my code looks like;

```
for file in *.deb; do
 name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.][^.]*\)\.deb$/\1/')
 echo $name
done
```

Comment: Since you asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10277736/7552) 2 hours later, you might as well close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want negative matching so you can exclude dots from the part of the string that you want to capture.  I also anchored the string so that you don't get a nasty surprise on a name like `com.deboop.foo.deb`.

```
name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.][^.]*\)\(_[-.0-9][-.0-9]*_arm\)*\.deb$/\1/')
```

(edited to reflect comments)

Comment: apparently, there's some files that are named something like com.coy. **name** _0.01_arm.deb within the same dir, how about these?

Comment: Are the `_`s part of the name?  Also I would suggest finding a regex resource and learning how to construct these yourself instead of relying on other people to do so for you.  But as written:  `^.*\([^.][^.]*\)\(_[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*_arm\)*\.deb$`.

Comment: i understand the basics but when it gets to these stages, it's really tough to understand, but I'm trying. :)

Comment: Sorry, that question was ambiguous; I was asking if they were there for emphasis or as actual characters in the original filename.

Comment: they are there in the file name as characters. some files would look like org.test. **app** _1.2.3-4_arm.deb

Comment: Yet another variation not mentioned.  Any other surprises?  Updated the main answer to reflect these.

Comment: sorry bro, wasn't expecting so many variations to occur. I'll try out again. thanks man! with all these {/\}[ is there a generator to do these?

Answer (score 1):

```
$> cat text
com.test.app1.deb
com.heavy.test.app2.deb
com.maybe-test.app3.deb
com.crazy.app-4.deb

$> sed -r "s/.*\.([^\.]*)\.deb$/\1/" ./text
app1
app2
app3
app-4
```

Comment: +1 But I don't think the `.` needs to backslashed inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
pearl.238> cat file1
com.test.app1.deb
com.heavy.test.app2.deb
com.maybe-test.app3.deb
com.crazy.app-4.deb
pearl.239> awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}' file1
app1
app2
app3
app-4
pearl.240>
```

you should use the below in your script.

```
name=$(echo $file |awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}')
```