# How to extract name of file?

Tags: linux, sed, filenames

In a dir i have some files which looks something like;

org.coy.**application**_0.1-2_arm.deb

com.cpo.**app2**_1.2.1_arm.deb

sg.team.works.**app3a**_1.33_arm.deb

com.share.**name4**.deb

com.sha-re.**app5**.deb

com.sha.re.**anything**.deb

I only require the bolded names.

here's what i have so far;

```
for file in *.deb; do
 name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.][^.]*\)\.deb$/\1/')
 echo $name
done
```

Comment: do they all match the following pattern? "app[0-9][a-z]*"

Comment: Requirement needs to be precise. Do you require 3rd part **separated by .**? Do you require part that **begins with app**?

Comment: requirements stated was pretty simple, i only require the bolded/application names. the rest in front or the numbers behind are not required. this is a small part of a larger code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *.deb
do
    name=${i%.deb}      #<-- remove extension      (.deb)
    name=${name%%_*}    #<-- remove version        (_x.y.z_arm)
    name=${name##*.}    #<-- remove namespace      (comp.x.y.z)
    echo $name
done
```

---

#### output

```
app2
anything
app5
name4
application
app3a
```

Comment: I had an idea similar to this, but was limited by my knowledge. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use dpkg-query with appropriate options. Check [For more information](http://man.he.net/man1/dpkg-query)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the basename command to make things a bit easier

```
for file in *.deb; do
 name=`basename $file | sed -e 's/.*\.//' -e 's/_.*//'`
 echo $name
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -e '
    do { 
        printf qq[%s\n], $+{my} 
            if $ARGV[0] =~ m/(?(?=.*_)\.(?<my>[^._]+)_\d|.*\.(?<my>[^.]+)\.deb\Z)/ 
    } while shift && @ARGV
' *.deb
```

Explanation of the regexp:

```
(?                          # Conditional expression.
(?=.*_)                     # Positive look-ahead to check if exits '_' in the string.
\.(?<my>[^._]+)_\d          # If previous look-ahead succeed, match string from a '.' until
                            # first '_' followed by a number.
|                           # Second alternative when look-ahead failed.
.*\.(?<my>[^.]+)\.deb\Z     # Match from '.' until end of string in '.deb'
```

As I'm using named captures, perl 5.10 or above is needed.

Output:

```
app2
anything
app5
name4
application
app3a
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
for file in *.deb; do
    name=$(echo "$file" |  sed 's/.*\.\([a-zA-Z][^_.]*\).*\.deb/\1/')
    echo $name
done
```