# How to get date and string separately in a given file name using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I am trying to get the date and string separately from the given file name but not getting exact idea how to do it.

This is the file name  "95FILRDF01PUBLI20170823XEURC0V41000.XML"
I want to extract date "20170823" and string "XEUR" from this file name.

I was going through lots of posts in Stackexchange/Stackoverflow, but didn't understand the regular expression they are using.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182563/how-to-extract-a-part-of-file-name-in-unix-linux-shell-script

[Extract part of filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275818/extract-part-of-filename)

Comment: Well, you have made things somewhat difficult on yourself by making it hard to *anchor* the beginning of a regular expression to extract the date. (mixed letters/number throughout with no real pattern except to check every 8 characters as a date) Will the date always have `PUBLI` before it or `XEUR` following it? (or are you just talking about this one filename?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract date and name:

```
$ name="95FILRDF01PUBLI20170823XEURC0V41000.XML"
$ echo "$name" | sed -E 's/.*([[:digit:]]{8})([[:alpha:]]{4}).*/date=\1 name=\2/'
date=20170823 name=XEUR
```

The key part of the regex is `([[:digit:]]{8})([[:alpha:]]{4})`.   The first part of that, `([[:digit:]]{8})` matches 8 digits and saves them as group 1.  The second part of that, `([[:alpha:]]{4})` matches four letters that follow the date and saves them as group 2.

The key part is surrounded by `.*` before and `.*` after which matches whatever is left over.

The replacement text is `date=\1 name=\2` which formats the output.

Comment: Ok, good answer, but what if another 8+4 appears before the date?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you point is that the question might be under-specified, well, then you are exactly correct.  The OP will have to let us know more.

Comment: No, no, I'm not dinging your answer (I voted it up). I thought about the same thing, but then wasn't sure whether he was taking about this one filename or a whole directory where there could be misses. Like I said, Good answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I understood that.  Thank you.  Sorry, I didn't intend for it to sound otherwise.

Comment: All good, I was just doing 2-things at once and misread the first part of you comment and wanted to make sure you knew I agreed 100% with the answer and I now see we were on the same sheet of paper to begin with.

Comment: @ John and @David thanks for your answers. I only have this file pattern in my directory.